# GNU gettext tools not found compiling error

Tags: ubuntu, gnu

I was compiling linphone source code in ubuntu linux.
And got the following error:

> GNU gettext tool not found #required for intltool

I doubt that intltool is not installed or
GNU tool is not in good condition. I don't know
where can I download the software for install.

I'll be appreciated if someone got me an answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use apt repository like this :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install gettext libgettextpo-dev
```

and you can take a look for full gettext targets available using apt-cache :

```
apt-cache search gettext | grep gettext
```

Answer (score 5):

Thks anyway,

I 'd already found the way out .

I can donlowad the GNU gettext tools down here:

http://www.icewalkers.com/Linux/Software/513960/gettext.html

And I solve the problem myself.

Comment: I really appreciate you posting how you solved your problem; it's a rare event. You helped me solve the same problem.